# Fonts not found with relative routes in css with bootstrap, bower and symfomy 2

Tags: symfony, routes, bower, assets

I'm working in a Symfony 2 project with Bower to manage all frontend packages of my site. My web application uses assetic and UglifyCSS/JS to minify and compress all assets.

I created a .bowerrc file to specify the directory to store the packages(inside an AssetsBundle) and use it using Assetic and UglifyCSS/JS via assets:install and assetic:dump.

```
{
  "directory": "src/efor/CoreBundle/Resources/public/bower_plugins"
}
```

All this is working nice and there are no problems with compressed assets.

My problem is about the Bootstrap package installed with Bower, the bootstrap.css file requires the fonts folder located one level up and them are included there like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  ...
}
```

When I minify all files with UglifyXX and reload the site I found this error/s in Chrome Console:

```
GET -> http://www.mywebsite.local/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2(404 Not Found)
...
```

The real location of that file(Fonts) should be http://www.mywebsite.local/bundles/core/bower_plugins/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Then, I have to specify anyway the location of inside css files to another external resources because relative routes are not working, but I don't know how, because if I modify the routes inside the css files of the installed package, when I update this to a upper version I will miss all my changes and it is a bad practice.

Any suggestion about how to do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Regards to all ¡

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you add this to your config [cf documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#cookbook-assetic-cssrewrite) :

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

Comment: I have tried that configuration for assetic, but it doesnt works, and it shows me an error about generating the name of the assets.